# QTableView - add named row

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

Im using a using a `QTableView` in conjuction with table model derived from `QAbstaractTableModel`. Now I want to insert rows/columns (which represent states/input chars) but I need to pass a string as a label (which is then shown in the HeaderView) for state/input char down to my data classes.

```
bool TransTableModel::insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index)
{
    beginInsertRows(index, position, position+rows-1);

    garage->addUsedState("q6");

    endInsertRows();
}
```

`TransTableModel` is my custom model. My problem: how do I obtain this string from user? In this case I hardcoded `"q6"` as a label, but I need this to be user-supplied. Is there a way? Should I open an input dialog? From the model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the model needs that data, it should be provided by the view which could then open an input dialog.

You can add a member function to your model to pass that extra parameter and call it from the view class instead of calling the "regular" `insertRows` (you don't have to call `insertRows` in that new function either, just `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows`).